# GNU parallel escaped character that is not intend to escape

Tags: bash, shell, gnu-parallel

```
parallel --dry-run wget {1} :::: <(echo "http:://a&b")
```

produces

```
wget http:://a\&b
```

How do I prevent the `\` before `&`? I've tried the option `-q`, but the output is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `eval`:

```
parallel --dry-run eval wget {1} :::: <(echo "http:://a&b")
```

In URLs you typically want the escaping, though, because otherwise you are starting `wget` in the background and running the command `b`.

Here is a (contrived) example where it *does* make sense:

```
parallel eval echo {} :::: <(echo "this & echo that")
```

A less contrived example is in the man page: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Aggregating-content-of-files